# How can the Address condition in a Match conditional block in sshd_config be negated?

Tags: ssh, cygwin-sshd

I would like to force users into a specific command when they log in from outside my LAN via SSH to my LAN. My idea was, to use `ForceCommand` in a `Match` conditional block, that matches all addresses except for the ones in my LAN.

I have tried the following, according to [`man 5 sshd_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5):

- `Match Address !192.168.1.0/24` allowed users from anywhere to execute any command.
- `Match Address !192.168.*` allowed users from anywhere to execute any command.
- `Match !Address 192.168.*` prevented execution of any command by means of `sshd` refusing to start.

Negating a pattern using `!` is described in [`man 5 ssh_config` (Section "Patterns")](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5#end). How can this be applied to addresses?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/44868/115189), for some unknown reason, you need to add a wildcard match in order to do this. CIDR notation does however seem to work. For example:

```
Match Address *,!192.168.1.0/24
    ForceCommand /bin/false
```

This works for me with OpenSSH 5.9p1.